# About Bug EXTJS-27596

Tags: extjs

I was wondering about the state of this bug: EXTJS-27596

Asked here: https://forum.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?470447-Spreadsheet-selection-is-broken-in-locked-grid-Ext-6-6-0

The problem can easily be reproduced in the mentioned demo:
https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/examples/kitchensink/?classic#spreadsheet

If you try to select several cells with mouse dragging the js-console will be spammed with errors.

Currently I don't see any way to work around this issue. The failing listener is a private function so I cannot hook into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check this by running the example with a newer version. Then you would see pretty fast whether it is fixed or not. You could also check the release notes.

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/guides/whats_new/release_notes.html

Here you will find an entry: "Grid EXTJS-27300 Spreadsheet Selection Issues"

A fiddle with version 6.7 shows that the problem is solved in this version.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/35vu